# How to use kafka json schema registry?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to build a application which will publish json messages to kafka topic. We have schema registry enabled on the topic. I am following the [kafka documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/serdes-json.html#using-schema-annotation-on-the-java-object) **but I am getting below error.**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:399)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:436)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.config.AbstractConfig.getConfiguredInstance(AbstractConfig.java:421)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:388)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.newInstance(Utils.java:395)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/guava/GuavaModule
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.<init>(AbstractKafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.java:43)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.<init>(KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.java:43)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 45 common frames omitted
```

**Here is the dependencies I am using.**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.confluent/kafka-json-serializer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-json-schema-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Here is my producer code **

```
@Bean
    public KafkaProducer<String, Object> jsonKafkaProducer() {

        Properties configProps = new Properties();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, CLIENT_ID);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG, SECURITY_MECHANISM);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, SSL_TYPE);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, kafkaTruststore);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, kafkaTruststorePassword);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_TYPE_CONFIG, SSL_TYPE);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG, kafkaKeystore);
        configProps.put(SslConfigs.SSL_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_CONFIG, kafkaKeystorePassword);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 3);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.json.KafkaJsonSchemaSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer.class);

        configProps.put("auto.register.schemas", false);
        configProps.put("schema.registry.url", schemaRegistryUrl);
        configProps.put("basic.auth.credentials.source", basicAuthCredSrc);
        configProps.put("basic.auth.user.info", basicAuthUserInfo);
        return new KafkaProducer<String, Object>(configProps);
    }
```

Comment: Try adding jackson guava dependency to your POM